# How to use WRITE_APN_SETTINGS ICS below

Tags: android

As i known WRITE_APN_SETTINGS is locked starting from android 4.0 . But for lower version it is possible.

Eclipse with last installed plugin v21.1. doesnt allow me to write it in manifest. (Error appears "Permission is only granted to system apps").

How do I do that?

Comment: set target version bellow 14 and clean the project might help

Comment: After you have set your target below 14, application won't work on 4.0 and 4.0+. You can only make your app work on up-to 3.0.

Comment: @AthulHarikumar how about turning your comment into an answer?